# Gravity Form query string appends '|:||:||:||:|2372' to the end of the data

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

Right now I'm trying to create a custom confirmation page to be displayed to the user after they finish filling out one of my forms. This custom confirmation page will use some of the data that they entered into the form. Right now I only have 3 fields: name, phone number, and a logo image.

So I went into the Settings->Confirmations section of my form and set Confirmation Type to Page, chose the page, and checked off 'Pass Field Data Via Query String'. Then I entered in the string 'gym_name={Gym/Program Name:2}&gym_phone={Gym/Program website and/or phone number:3}&logo={Logo:4}'. The logo parameter is passed as the image src url.

I ran through a quick test of my form and after filling it out, all of the data was successfully sent to the confirmation page, with one problem. For some reason, Gravity Form appends '|:||:||:||:|2372' (it's not always 2372, it's different every time) to the end of the logo section of the url. This happens no matter where in the query string I put logo, and it does not get appended if I don't include the logo.

Does anyone know what the cause of this is, and how to stop it? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the Logo field is a Post Image field. If so, you'll need to use the *:url* modifier to retrieve only the URL.

`&logo={Logo:4:url}`

More details here: https://docs.gravityforms.com/post-image-merge-tags/

Comment: I didn't know about the modifier, so thank you for that! But even with that modifier, the weird string is still being appended to the end.

Comment: Oh, and you're right in your assumption that the Logo field is a Post Image field.

Comment: I would expect that to work. I'd ping Gravity Forms support if you haven't already.